# String and Variable concatenation not working in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to concatenate at variable within a path name string to make this script more efficient.
This is the code I have so far. But I can't seem to find the right syntax needed in order to set the  variable in the string.

```
    set vserver to POSIX file "/Volumes/johndoe"
    set user to "johndoe" as string

    set source to POSIX file "/Users/johndoe/Documents"

    tell application "Finder"

        duplicate source to vserver with replacing
    end tell
```

I want johndoe to be replaces by variable user to make the code more maintainable for the future. My ultimate goal is to be able to copy multiple home folders including: movies, pictures, documents etc... onto a shared server.

I tried doing this

```
"/Users/" & user & "/Desktop"
```

But I received this error:

> "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class."
>   number -10010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run

```
set user to "johndoe"
set source to POSIX file "/Users/" & user & "/Documents"
```

the result is

```
{file "Macintosh HD:Users:", "johndoe", "/Documents"}
```

Just put parentheses around the path:

```
set user to "johndoe"
set source to POSIX file ("/Users/" & user & "/Documents")
```