# How to use a variable inside a path in AppleScript?

Tags: finder, applescript, macos

```
tell application "System Events"
name of current user
end tell
tell application "System Events"
set answer to name of current user
end tell
tell application "Finder"
delete ((POSIX file "/Users/answer/Desktop/untitled folder"))
end tell
tell application "Finder"
empty the trash
end tell
```

I want to make a universal code to delete this specific folder but I can't seem to make my variable (=answer) work in the quoted path.

```
answer
```

.

```
delete ((POSIX file "/Users/answer/Desktop/untitled folder"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following lines of **AppleScript** *code* replaces all of the *code* in your OP:

```
set thisFolder to POSIX path of (path to desktop folder as string) & "untitled folder"
try
    tell application "System Events" to delete folder thisFolder
end try
```

Note that this **directly deletes** `thisFolder` and its contents, **bypassing** the **Trash**, so be sure this is what you want before using it!

As coded, if `thisFolder` does not exist, the `try` *command* keeps it from fatally halting execution of the *code*. In other words, you'll not get an error message and it will continue processing additional *code* in the *script*, if any.

Comment: I like your "KISS" approach (as you mentioned the other day in a different post) with your answer here  +1 ;P

Answer (score 1):

You need to [use string concatenation](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/applescript-the-missing/0596008503/ch04s03.html) to get your variable in the string. Specifically in your case something like `"/Users/" & answer & "/Desktop/untitled folder"` should work, though you may need to wrap that in parenthesis as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123595/239027)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR you have to use string concatenation (as moneyt mentioned in his answer) and convert it to a colon path as string:

```
-- Get and set name of current user
tell application "System Events"
    set UserName to name of current user
end tell

-- Create POSIX path string
set PosixPath to "/Users/" & UserName & "/Desktop/" & "untitled folder"

-- Convert POSIX path into colon path
set ColonPath to (POSIX file PosixPath) as string

-- Delete folder and empty trash
tell application "Finder"
    delete ColonPath
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    empty the trash
end tell
```

A simpler version without user-defined variables but reverting to a Finder property in the AppleScript suite "Finder Basics" (***home*** (folder, r/o) : the home directory) is:

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete folder "untitled folder" of folder "Desktop" of home
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    empty the trash
end tell
```

---

Please don't use simple variable names like "answer" because they may conflict with AppleScript's reserved variables/strings!

Answer (score 0):

If you run the script while being logged in as the user that you want to delete the directory for, you can just use this as your file path `~/Desktop/`
The tilde(~) symbolizes `/Users/[Current username]`

Comment: AppleScript doesn't take relative pathnames.  *~/Desktop* would throw an error.

Comment: But bashscripts in AppleScript does